# QComboBox list popup display in Fusion style

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qcombobox

I am using PyQt5. I want to know how to make my QComboBox open with ±10 items instead of the full screen. This only happens with the fusion style applied. Is there any way I can make this behave with a small drop down instead? I have tried to use `setMaxVisibleItems(5)`, but it didn't make a difference.

Here is what it is looking like now:

[image: example]

Comment: Make sure that you use ComboBox.setMaxVisibleItems(5) on the created Combobox variable. Otherwise this should work. Further help is only possible if you show the code of your combobox.

Comment: in my code i did us it on the created combo box there are quite a few combos in my forms and they all have the same appearance where it shows a massive list instead, I don't really have any code to show on the actual combo boxes, if I change the style from fusion to windows or windowsVista then it works as intended,

Comment: Possibly related to [QTBUG-89037](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89037).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in [QTBUG-89037](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89037), there's an undocumented stylesheet property that can be used to change the behaviour of the popup:

```
setStyleSheet('QComboBox {combobox-popup: 0}')
```

A value of `0` will show the normal scrollable list-view with a maximum number of visible items, whilst a value of `1` shows the humungous menu.

However, in some circumstances, setting a stylesheet may have undesirable side-effects, since it could potentially interfere with the default behaviour of QStyle. So an alternative solution might be to use a [proxy-style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html), and reimplement its [styleHint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html#styleHint) method so that it returns either `0` or `1` for [QStyle.SH_ComboBox_Popup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StyleHint-enum).

Both of these solutions work with both Qt5 and Qt6, and will also work for styles such as "cleanlooks" as well as "fusion".

Here's a simple demo that implements both solutions:

[image: screenshot]

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
# from PyQt6 import QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItems(f'Item-{i:02}' for i in range(1, 50))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)

class ProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def styleHint(self, hint, option, widget, data):
        if hint == QtWidgets.QStyle.StyleHint.SH_ComboBox_Popup:
            return 0
        return super().styleHint(hint, option, widget, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Combo Test'])

    app.setStyle('fusion')
#     app.setStyle('cleanlooks')
#     style = ProxyStyle(app.style())
#     app.setStyle(style)

    app.setStyleSheet('QComboBox {combobox-popup: 0}')

    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 200, 75)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: According to the above [QTBUG-89037](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89037), it seems that using `QComboBox { combobox-popup: 0; }` (even as a QApplication style sheet) may be enough too. Which is a bit controversial, since using a QSS may invalidate some virtuals of the current QStyle, and, therefore, using a proxy style may become useless as long as QSS are set.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks. I very rarely use stylesheets, so I admit I never even considered that kind of solution. It's a little disturbing that `combobox-popup` isn't documented, but I suppose it does offer a simpler solution for those who use stylesheets, so I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome. In fact, there are a few undocumented aspects of QSS, including some style hints. See the `knownStyleHints` in the qstylesheetstyle.cpp file.

Comment: setStyleSheet('QComboBox {combobox-popup: 0}') this worked like a charm, thank you so much for the assist